# How find new element on page after ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem to find current html elements after - ajax response and deleted them from page.

Here is jQuery code that send post and delete some element from page.
after refresh i want find element that stay in page - but I dont know why I got all elements - I use callback function.

```
            function removeProduct(callback) {
            var recordchosen = $(this);
            var recordToDelete = recordchosen.attr("data-id");  
            if (recordToDelete != '') {

                // Send post request with AJAX
                $.post("/Cart/RemoveFromCart", { "albumID": recordToDelete },
                    function (response) {
                        // Success      
                        $('#productCart-' + response.prodID).fadeOut('slow', function () {

                            if (response.productsCart == 0) {
                                $("#cartEmpty").removeClass("hidden");
                            }
                            callback();
                        });
                        var textCart = $("#cartbox").text();
                        var amountCart = (parseInt(textCart) - 1);
                        $("#cartbox").text(amountCart);

                    });

                return false;

            };

        };

        $(".removeProduct").click(function () {
            removeProduct.call(this, updateTotal);
        });
```

Here avery think look ok but when the callback method start

```
function updateTotal() {
            var $priceElement = $(".products").find('td.customerValue');
            var $totalValue = 0;
```

In priceElement I have 4 element but should by 3 because previous I delete one.

So what to do, to have in callback method correct element that exist after using js to delete them from page?
Sorry for pure english:)

Comment: You need to add your HTML. Is `td.customerValue` a child of `.products`?

Comment: Yes, .products is a table and customerValue is td